# Folder Recovery after upgradation

Tags: data-recovery

Hi I upgraded my ubuntu 10.10 to 12.04 and I found one folder named 'www' inside '/var' was missing Can you plese tell me how to recocver it .

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this probably can't be done, as 10.10's `/` partition has been overwritten by 12.04's `/`. It is recommended to take a backup of **all** important files before upgrading your system.